# One-season comedic satire about a modern Hollywood producer

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

There was a one-season TV satiric comedy that aired on a major U.S. network, something like ten years ago, about a sleazy Hollywood producer struggling to get a film made.  He hires a prostitute to assist, and her first job is to cajole the writer retained to turn out the script.  The first too-shallow attempt at satire involves him trying to get the prostitute to take the job:  When she explains that she makes over $200k in cash a year as a hooker, he says something like, "Oh, well, I guess if you took this Hollywood job you'd be doing the same thing but for less money."

There is at least one episode in which the producer surreptitiously records a sex tape with Sandra Bullock (cameo as herself) to sell for money.  When she discovers it she angrily confronts him in public.

In the last episodes they're filming on a sound stage and as he tells everyone they need to cut back on spending he grabs a golf bag and boards a helicopter to get to his tee time.  The star actor of the film being made is also a divo who demands the largest codpiece and retires to his trailer to practice when his line is changed to, "It's time."  The season ends with the producer having a heart attack and as he's loaded onto an ambulance one EMT says to the other, "That's a nice watch."  What is the name of the show and when did it air?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question.

This has to be [***Action***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0206467/) (1999-2000) starring Jay Mohr.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(TV_series))

> *Action* is an American comedy series about a Hollywood producer named Peter Dragon, who is trying to recover from his last box-office failure.

---

> Wendy Ward, played by Illeana Douglas, is a former child actress who gained fame as the cute star of the TV show, The Elephant Princess (not to be confused with The Elephant Princess). Her career tanked during her teen years due to a nasty coke habit, and she is now **a high priced call girl**. Through circumstance, she ends up becoming Peter's date at the premiere of his movie Slow Torture. After she gives her honest criticism of Slow Torture, **Wendy is named Vice President of Production at Dragonfire Films**-- and has an open relationship with Peter.

---

> Sandra Bullock vehemently protests the sex tape of her and Peter that he is selling on his website. (Episode #103)

Comment: Yes, that's it!  I was baffled trying to find it.  Thanks!